# Sort strings by trailing numeric substring (naturally), then by leading alphabetic substring

Tags: php, sorting, alphanumeric, usort, custom-sort

I have an array of strings which are consistently formatted as a letter followed by a number.  I need to sort them by number first then by letter.

Sample input:

```
$data = [
    'A1',
    'A2',
    'A5',
    'A10',
    'B2',
    'B4',
    'C10',
    'B5',
    'C1',
    'B1',
    'C2',
];
```

I need the following result:

```
[
    'A1',
    'B1',
    'C1',
    'A2',
    'B2',
    'C2',
    'B4',
    'A5',
    'B5',
    'A10',
    'C10',
]
```

Comment: Looks more to me like sorting by number and then by alphabet

Comment: Are these Excel spreadsheet cell references?

Answer (score 2):

[usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) allows you to create a custom sort rule, so you can create a rule that splits the value into letters and digits, and compare those

```
usort(
    $data,
    function($a, $b) {
        sscanf($a, '%[A-Z]%d', $ac, $ar);
        sscanf($b, '%[A-Z]%d', $bc, $br);
        return ($ar == $br) ? $ac <=> $bc : $ar <=> $br;
    }
);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Y52lv)

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_multisort()` to sort on two rules, first remove the non-digital characters and sort by integer value, then sort normally by the leading string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Lq8tF))

```
array_multisort(preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $data), SORT_NUMERIC, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient, but quite laconic approach will be to use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) and [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
array_multisort(
    array_map(function ($item) { return substr($item, 1); },$array),
    array_map(function ($item) { return $item[0]; },$array),
    $array
);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fef8e9f4df68ab6c54a524c8be54b5bd835c46f1).